# Excel lookup w/ 2 criteria, date between two dates & matching id's

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Sample Data:

```
id,action_datetime,value_id,
770940,03/15/2018 23:00:04,??,
801816,03/15/2018 22:45:49,??,
,,,
id,start_datetime,end_datetime,value_id
801816,03/15/2018 21:30:07,03/15/2018 21:55:29,595774419
774137,03/15/2018 22:38:35,03/15/2018 23:05:24,595777227
801816,03/15/2018 22:54:57,03/15/2018 23:02:16,595777156
647428,03/15/2018 22:53:48,03/15/2018 23:01:23,595777127
813437,03/15/2018 22:47:06,03/15/2018 23:01:04,595777115
801816,03/15/2018 22:42:03,03/15/2018 22:49:46,595776712
799132,03/15/2018 22:51:48,03/15/2018 23:00:30,595777071
813433,03/15/2018 22:48:10,03/15/2018 23:00:25,595777088
770940,03/15/2018 21:11:02,03/15/2018 22:10:45,595775340
792244,03/15/2018 22:56:44,03/15/2018 23:00:12,595777081
770940,03/15/2018 22:53:38,03/15/2018 23:00:32,595777094
647428,03/15/2018 22:40:46,03/15/2018 22:49:28,595776789
780946,03/15/2018 22:52:37,03/15/2018 23:00:48,595777105
800197,03/15/2018 22:48:26,03/15/2018 23:04:36,595777209
```

[image]

I need a **formula** that will return the **value_id** (Col J) where the **action_datetime** from Col B is between the **start_datetime** (Col H) and **end_datetime** (Col I) and the id from Col A matches the id from Col G.

I'd prefer a formula, but I could work with a VBA option too.

Any help would be great.  I don't know how to be more specific, but if you have questions, let me know.

Thank you,

Comment: Struggling with what? If you post what you've tried at least we could determine the correct columns and rows as well as several other details you've omitted.

Comment: @NiVeR extend office is a paid excel add on. Probably not helpful in this situation.

Comment: You'll need to, at the very least, post a sample of your data if you want a point in the  right direction.  Your question might make sense to you but you have to realize there is an infinite number of way that infinite types of data can be laid out.  I could *guess* what you have, but currently it makes no more definitive sense than the proposed answer does to you: **Use a combination of Lookup functions as required to retrieve the data you need.**  (please see also: [ask] and also [mcve])

Comment: I added in a sample data set & clarified the ask.  I think it is fairly clear & concise now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the rages on this formula based on your data sets:

```
{=INDEX(H$2:H$15,MATCH(1,IF(B2>=F$2:F$15,IF(B2<=G$2:G$15,IF(A2=$E$2:$E$15,1))),0))}
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate the formula.

[image]

Comment: The date check needs to look at the entire set rather than just one row.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: That was it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In cell H2: =LOOKUP(G2,$B$2:$C$16,$D$2:$D$16)
[image]

This was created before the question was revised so the setup may not match yours exactly.

Credit: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/621562-vlookup-if-date-between-2-dates-table.html

P.S. after looking at revised question, this may work better for you. In Cell C2: =vlookup(A2,$G$2:$J$15, 4,FALSE) and in Cell C3: =vlookup(A3,$G$2:$J$15